# How can I use DexGuard to obfuscate my apk?

Tags: android, android-studio, obfuscation, dexguard

How can I use DexGuard to obfuscate my apk? I know how to enable proguard and its customization. Can anyone suggest a good tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

You also could try DexProtector (http://dexprotector.com) out, it has trial period. And it is much easier in configuration than DexGuard.

N.B.
I am Licel's CEO, thus I am affiliated with DexProtector.

Answer (score 2):

DexGuard works in a similar way to Proguard and handily the config for Proguard is compatible with DexGuard so if your already using ProGuard it's a simple upgrade. Once you purchase DexGuard in the download bundle there's a bunch of sample apps with defined DexGuard configuration for all of the features i.e String/class encryption, tamper detection etc. I started by copying the config from these sample apps and then started combining some of the features to further harden.

a happy DexGuard customer

Comment: Hi sorry for random comment, How do you personally customize dexguard for your project? I.e. how what files do you need to change the config etc in? thanks

Comment: In my gradle project i have a dexgaurd.pro file with my customisations. But this is covered in the docs, <dexguard dir>docs/index.html check the `getting started` section.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I can see this. I am using Ant to build my project but it is developed in eclipse, what file should I use to set up custom configs? Is it the custom_rules.xml?

Comment: typically it's dexguard-project.txt for ant builds, but check the /samples the projects in there should be a good starting point

Comment: Thanks for your help, do you know what the custom rules file is used for? Also, how does dexguard carry out any obfuscation automatically? I ask as my dexguard-project.txt file is currently only filled with comments yet my output is still obfuscated.

Comment: If you look in your `build.xml` file, you'll see it loads in the `custom_rules.xml` file (if it exists) which in turn execute the dexguard tasks. obfuscation is enabled by default, you can disable with `-dontobfuscate` in your dexgaurd-project.txt.

Answer (score 0):

To use DexGuard you first need to buy a license.
Take a look at their [pricing](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard).

Comment: Link is now invalid.  Pricing now seems to be "Ask Me" which usually means expensive.